# Accessing guest VM source code from MAC Xcode

Tags: xcode, macos, virtualbox

I am new to MAC and Xcode. I had been developing my code on Ubuntu Virtual box on host os MAC. But just wondered how wonderful Xcode as IDE is. So is it possible to access code on Ubuntu VM from Xcode on MAC?

Any pointers will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this in 2 different ways:

1. Use `shared folders` feature in the virtual box. See [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23514244/share-folders-from-the-host-mac-os-to-a-guest-linux-system-in-virtualbox) for more.
2. Use `NFS` (network file system) to mount a folder in ubuntu (nfs server) into macOS (nfs client). See [link1](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apple-mac-osx-nfs-mount-command-tutorial/), [link2](https://serverfault.com/questions/716350/mount-nfs-volume-on-ubuntu-linux-server-from-macos-client) for more.